# <lightning:input type="toggle"> how to set the slds-checkbox--on and the slds-checkbox--off span text

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightninginput

I am using `lightning:input type="toggle"` base component and I need to set the text underneath the toggle button.

By default `checked` displays `Active`:

[image]

And `unchecked` displays `Inactive`:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<lightning:input type="toggle"
                 label="My Label: "
                 name="toggle"
                 checked="{!v.record.myCheckbox__c}"/>
```

I want to change these messages and cannot find a way to do it - is there a way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use messageToggleActive and messageToggleInactive:

```
<lightning:input name="x"
                 label="x"
                 type="toggle"
                 messageToggleActive="Done"
                 messageToggleInactive="Not Done" />
```

---

[image: Not Done]

---

[image: Done]

Comment: Works like a charm! so many Attributes for this component so I have missed these. Thanks

Comment: @sfdcfox: Where did you find this info coz I was looking for the same. Thanks for the answer. Update: As soon as I typed "mes.." viscode showed me the options. Should have thought of that.

Comment: @ankittaneja It's [in the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/specification).